# PHP MySQL return columns with same value

Tags: php, mysql

For example I have table:

```
ID   |   Nickname   |      IP     |
----------------------------------|
1.   |  CustomNick  |  127.0.0.1  |
2.   |  NickCustom  |  127.0.0.1  |
```

Now I'm passing info by this code:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM players WHERE Nickname = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['player_session']));

$playerInfo = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) :
    return $playerInfo;
endif;
```

I'm printing value with this `$info['columnName']`. And my queston is, how can I check by logged player ID, does he have more accounts with this IP address? If yes, print these account nicknames

For example if I login to `customNick`, then output: CustomNick has one more account with this IP (NickCustom). Sorry for my bad English and thanks in advance

Comment: Get the IP, then search for it in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your solution..

**Method 1: Subquery**

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM players WHERE IP = (SELECT IP FROM players WHERE Nickname = ?)");
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['player_session']));
```

**Method 2: Join**

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM players p1 INNER JOIN players p2 ON p1.IP = p2.IP WHERE p1.Nickname = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['player_session']));
```